# How does one construct the delegate / response handler pattern as used in HTTPBuilder?

Tags: http, groovy

I want to write an asynchronous function that accepts a closure with handlers like HTTPBuilder.request does. How is the function written?

When I call the function, it will look like this:

```
// calling my function now - we'll process the results when status is available...
myFunction(arg1, arg2) {
  status.success = { result ->
    println 'cool'
  }
  status.failure = { result ->
    println 'not cool'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "body" of `myFunction` is actually a third parameter of type `Closure`.  When you declare it, it will actually have three parameters: `arg1`, `arg2`, and one more containing the body.

In `myFunction` call the body closure with a delegate.  The delegate holds the `status.success` and `status.failure` event handler closures.  Then do your async operation and capture the result.  Finally, invoke the appropriate result handler closure.  The skeleton for a function like this would look something like this:

```
def myFunction(arg1, arg2, Closure body) {
    def delegateMap = [status:[:]]
    body.delegate = delegateMap
    body.call()

    // start async process
    Thread.start {
         def result = doAsyncStuff()
         if (isSuccess(result) && delegateMap.status.success) {
             delegateMap.status.success.call(result)
         }
         else if (isFailure(result) && delegateMap.status.failure) {
             delegateMap.status.failure.call(result)
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I implemented this pattern in my Grails controller. I don't get any errors, but the controller renders immediately without waiting for the thread. The same style of call with HTTPBuilder keeps the browser waiting until a handler fires - which displays the result. How can I make Grails wait for my Thread to display a result? I don't have anything in my controller after the call, so I'm not sure why it's rendering and not waiting for my handlers.

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but "Warning The [myFunction] action accepts a parameter of type [groovy.lang.Closure] which has not been marked with @Validateable.  Data binding will still be applied to this command object but the instance will not be validateable."

Comment: Just remove the `Thread.start` and it won't return until the whole thing is done.

Comment: I guess I did say that I wanted an async function. This has been very instructive - thanks @ataylor!

Comment: Not sure about the `@Validateable` warning without context.  If `myFunction` is in a controller, it might be interpreted as an action.  Make it private to stop that.